websoket на python
Написал websoket, который непрерывно получает цену.
async def TickersChannel_ws():

    """ Websoket подписка на цены"""
    url = "wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:

        subs = {
            "op": "subscribe",
            "args": [
                dict(channel="mark-price", instId="NOT-USDT-SWAP")
            ]
        }

        await ws.send(json.dumps(subs))

        async for msg in ws:
            msg = json.loads(msg)
            if "event" not in msg:
                return msg.get("data")[0].get("markPx")

Мне теперь совсем непонятно, как сделать чтобы также в непрерывном потоке сравнивать цену из подписки asyncio.run(TickersChannel_ws()) с заданным числом к примеру. while True не вариант, потому что получается, что он постоянно переконекчивается к серверу, что теряет смысл сокета.
Я понимаю, что надо условно записывать в переменную, а потом сравнивать, но так у меня тоже не получается, потомучто сокет непрерывно идет.

Ваш код не позволяет воспроизвести проблему, вот например этот вопрос, там код не полный (тоже не позволяет воспроизвести проблему), но достаточный чтоб я смогла (что-то додумав (предположив)) локализовать проблему и предложить решение. Что мне не хватает: 1) фрагмента кода куда возвращается результат работы функции; 2) структура ws (если там содержатся данные данные которые не следует публиковать, то предварительно измените их (с сохранением типов); 3) заданное число  добавьте переменную с этим значением после url.

while True тут не нужно, просто с for будет работать, только return нужно убрать, чтобы он не прерывал цикл. Тут можно return заменить на print, например. Либо сделать функцию-генератор с yield вместо return, и в вызывающей функции через async for эти значения обрабатывать.

@insolor помогите плз, что мне написать после if name == "main": (после асинхронной функции) чтобы он сравнивал непрерывно значение из подписки, с уловно числом пять и выдавал непрерывно фолс к примеру.

import json
import asyncio
import websockets


async def TickersChannel_ws():
    url = "wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:

        subs = {
            "op": "subscribe",
            "args": [
                dict(channel="mark-price", instId="NOT-USDT-SWAP")
            ]
        }

        await ws.send(json.dumps(subs))

        async for msg in ws:
            msg = json.loads(msg)
            if "event" not in msg:
                yield msg.get("data")[0].get("markPx")


async def main():
    async for ticker in TickersChannel_ws():
        print(ticker)


asyncio.run(main())

